# Mysql calculate medium value of a count(*) with a group by somefield

Tags: mysql, select

I have this query:

```
select count(*) from logins group by user_id
```

this returns me the user logins number for each user:

Count(*)

---

10

23

35

54

With a single and efficient query, how can select (calculate) the medium value of this? medium = (10+23+35+54)/4.

Comment: This SHOULD be a separate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select avg(num_login) 
  from (select count(*) as num_login 
  from logins group by user_id) as num_logins
```

Comment: this works I will accept your answer since it was the first to give the right solution

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(count(*)) from logins group by user_id
```

Comment: you should try using the avg over the whole query (take a look at my answer)

Comment: i just tried it on my Oracle 11 - works for me... what error do you see?

Comment: It's not an oracle question. It's a mySQL question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM logins GROUP BY user_id) AS v
```

This works..

Comment: this works good, I hoped to find a simple query bug this seems good

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query and then `AVG` function on result of sub-query as:

```
SELECT AVG(logins_cnt) AS logins_cnt
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS logins_cnt
        FROM logins 
        GROUP BY user_id
       ) a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the average function?

```
select avg(select count(*) from logins group by user_id)
```